# Would dragons be able to purr?

Tags: science-based, creature-design, dragons, audio

My dragons have a... "difficult" personality.

They're very catlike. Sure, they're more like KrimsonRogue's cat (somewhere around chaotic good). But, if I want to make my dragons smug, blue-blood a-holes that you still want to cuddle, then I might as well give them the ability to purr very loudly.

Well, that actually would have one tangible advantage, if the dragon could use it to transmit data and instructions to the nanomachines in their body.

Problem is, dragons here are about as large as a draft horse, are filled with spongy and hollow structures on top of having air sacs to assist breathing, and I'm afraid that would ruin the acoustics.

Basically, there are two unique features to my dragons:

1. Air blubbers, a special type of aerogel, made out of fibrous, CNT-reinforced organic matter with densities around 200 kg/m^3.
   These air blubbers are primarily located under the dragon's skin, serving as protection against blunt force trauma (like crash-landing).
2. Air sacs and hollow bones are present throughout the body, as dragons have a respiratory system similar to birds'.

There's also that large cats (lions, tigers, etc...) can't purr.

**So, how would dragons be able to purr very loudly?**

Comment: put a cat inside of the dragon

Comment: @Topcode What's wrong with you?!

Comment: cat -> dragon. cat purrs -> dragon purrs absolutely flawless idea that makes perfect sense (;

Comment: @Topcode But I wanted a dragon that could purr so loud, the ground would start shaking.

Comment: With the correct physiology (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purr#Vocal_folds/laryngeal_muscles), it doesn't seem implausible for a large non-feline creature to purr nor does the question say anything about the dragons that would imply that they couldn't have the appropriate anatomical structure.

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan I'm worried it won't properly propagate across their body because of all the hollow, air-filled parts.

Comment: maybe add the detailed dragon anatomy in the context there so ppl can see what the problem that make them cant purr.

Comment: Topcode had the right idea, put the cat inside the dragon

Comment: @User24712 We don't do that here.

Comment: Re: propagation: Low frequency sound propagates extremely well and presumably the dragon has enough rigid internal structure to transmit vibrations through its body as well; shouldn't be a problem.  Re: shaking the ground, purring is a vocalization and the dragon is light enough to fly; there's probably not enough mass or energy for that.  (Strictly as an aside, the real mystery for me is what the reptilian evolutionary precursors of the dragon were that are also able to purr and why they evolved that capability independently from felines.)

Comment: @GrumpyYoungMan In-universe, they didn't as they were bio-engineered.

Comment: can parrot purr?

Comment: you forgot cheetas purr, and a dragon could purr, and it could also block the sound from being ruined by actually not letting it go from one point down, by flaps, wich close so the fire has minimall internal damage, if it gets out of control, give it one at a lower point and bam purring dragon, sorry if this isn't a good answer, i am right now going to go to sleep and i am tired

Comment: Birds make sounds in a completely different way from mammals. And there are birds which can imitate the sound of a cat purring.

Comment: Any creature that breathes air, and has muscles, can potentially purr. Biomechanically it is easy, it's just that most creatures don't exactly want to *advertise* their position. So purrs are rather reserved for apex predators. But I guess Dragons would qualify for that. P.S. Cats are not the only ceatures that purr. Elephants do, too!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### How Cat Purrs Work:

Cats purr based on a set of muscles in their larynx:

[image: https://www.discoveryexpresskids.com/your-questions-answered/how-do-cats-purr-natalie-h]

### How Big Cats Roar:

As to how we can let a dragon roar loudly, we can look at how [big cats roar](https://www.livescience.com/16826-lions-roar-vocal-cords.html#:%7E:text=When%20just%20a%20small%20puff,translate%20to%20a%20big%20sound.):

> "What's peculiar about the lion and tiger vocal folds is that they
> have a very flat surface on the front," Titze said. "It's almost like
> two parallel plates."
>
> When just a small puff of air is blown between these two plates,
> vibrations start, Titze said. That's one key to the roar of a lion or
> tiger: They need very little lung pressure to make large vibrations,
> which translate to a big sound.
>
> The second secret to a big cat's roar is a layer of fat within the
> vocal folds, where other animals have a ligament. Fat is squishy,
> offering more leeway for the vocal cords to vibrate, Titze said.

### Dragon Rawrs:

Generally speaking, big cats that can roar cannot purr, while small cats that can purr cannot roar. However, seeing as dragons are biologically engineered, perhaps one way to achieve this is to use **two sets of vocal cords in series**.

One set, deepest in the throat, would generate the purring sound, using something similar to the cat's larynx. The other set, higher up, would be like a big cat's vocal cords, with two parallel folds and a layer of fat, allowing sounds to be amplified into roars.

Like this, the two sets of vocal cords would allow three modes of operation: dragon roar, dragon purr, dragon purr roar.

This would allow the dragon to intimidate foes using its roars, purr when it is enticed by dragon-nip, or purr-roar as a vibrational sound attack.

Cute but deadly!

[image]